# Amazon RDS: plot number of instances in CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-aurora

How do I plot the number of instances in my AWS Aurora RDS cluster over time in CloudWatch?

There doesn't seem to be a metric for that.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed there is no metric for that.

**UPDATE:** the below trick is not 100% foolproof: when the dashboard range is set to `1d` or more, the display period automatically changes to 5 Minutes, which leads to values being off by a factor of 5.

The trick is to pick any RDS aggregated metric (for example `CPUUtilization`, aggregated per DB role), then select `Statistic: Sample Count` and `Period: 1 Minute`.

[image]

Comment: I'm surprised that there's no such metric... Based on your solution I figured out a better version with a custom function: `m1/PERIOD(m1) * 60`, normalize the sample counts with the period duration.