# How to create a Cloudwatch chart of the number Aurora Postgres read instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-aurora

Is it possible to create a Cloudwatch chart of the number of Aurora Postgres read replica instances?

This can be done easily for and EC2 auto-scaling group, but I don't see anything similar for Aurora read instance scaling.

I've searched the documents and list of available Cloudwatch metrics, but I can't find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had feedback that, in fact, there is no metric for the number of replica instances. But, I found this other post, which provides a work-around:

[Amazon RDS: plot number of instances in CloudWatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62919169/amazon-rds-plot-number-of-instances-in-cloudwatch)

Not the one answer, but the comment to it:

> I'm surprised that there's no such metric... Based on your solution I figured out a better version with a custom function: m1/PERIOD(m1) * 60, normalize the sample counts with the period duration.